# In how many ways can $2m$ objects be paired and assigned to $m$ boxes?

Tags: combinatorics

Been refreshing my statistics knowledge and came across this problem while going through a book.

> How many ways can $2m$ objects be paired and assigned to $m$ boxes?

The book claims the answer is

$$ \frac{(2m)!}{2^m} $$

Which makes sense, however, it further claims that if we want to arrange the pairs without assigning them to boxes, since there are $m!$ ways to assign the $m$ pairs to $m$ boxes, the answer is:

$$ \frac{(2m)!}{m!2^m} $$

Can someone explain why we have to divide by $m!$ if we are no longer assigning the pairs to boxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $k$ be the number of ways to pair up the objects.

If we want to pair them up and then assign the pairs to $m$ boxes, we can do this in 2 steps:

1) Pair them up, which can be done in $k$ ways.

2) Assign the $m$ pairs to the boxes, which can be done in $m!$ ways.

Therefore $\displaystyle k(m!)=\frac{(2m)!}{2^m},\;$ so $\displaystyle k=\frac{(2m)!}{(m!)2^m}$

Comment: Thanks, makes sense now! Appreciate the great response!

Comment: You're welcome -- I'm glad this was helpful.

Answer (score 5):

We divide by $m!$ because the arrangement (order and which boxes they are put into) matters. We can arrange the boxes in $m!$ ways and we would have a different arrangement. So we have to divide by $m!$ from the previous answer.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't fully understand your answer. The question states that we are no longer assigning the pairs to boxes but your answer says we divide by m! because the arrangement and which boxes they are put into matters.

Answer (score 1):

If $m = 1$, we have a set $\{1,2\}$ and there's only $1$ unordered pair we can form.

If $m = 2$, we have a set $\{1,2,3,4\}$ and there are $3$ pairings we can form, namely,

$$\{\{1,2\}, \{3,4\}\}$$

$$\{\{1,3\}, \{2,4\}\}$$

$$\{\{1,4\}, \{2,3\}\}$$

For a general $m$, we have a set $\{1,2,\dots,2m\}$ and the number of pairings we can form is the number of **partitions** of size $2$ of the set, which is given by the following **double factorial**

$$\begin{array}{rl} (2 m - 1)!! &= (2m-1) \cdot (2m-3) \cdot (2m-5) \cdots 3 \cdot 1\\\\ &= \dfrac{(2m-1) \cdot (2m-2) \cdot (2m-3) \cdots 2 \cdot 1}{(2m-2) \cdot (2m-4) \cdot (2m-6) \cdots 4 \cdot 2}\\\\ &= \dfrac{(2m) \cdot (2m-1) \cdot (2m-2) \cdot (2m-3) \cdots 2 \cdot 1}{(2m) \cdot(2m-2) \cdot (2m-4) \cdot (2m-6) \cdots 4 \cdot 2}\\\\ &= \dfrac{(2m) \cdot (2m-1) \cdot (2m-2) \cdot (2m-3) \cdots 2 \cdot 1}{2^m \cdot m \cdot(m-1) \cdot (m-2) \cdot (m-3) \cdots 2 \cdot 1}\\\\ &= \dfrac{(2m)!}{2^m \cdot m!}\end{array}$$

The total number of **assignments** of $m$ partitions of size $2$ to $m$ boxes is

$$m! \cdot (2m-1)!! = m! \cdot \dfrac{(2m)!}{2^m \cdot m!} = \dfrac{(2m)!}{2^m}$$

which is also given by

$$\binom{2m}{2} \binom{2m-2}{2} \binom{2m-4}{2} \cdots \binom{2}{2} = \dfrac{(2m)!}{2^m}$$

Comment: https://oeis.org/A001147